# Using "this" in a jquery multiple selector

Tags: jquery, selector, this

Im trying to figure this one out, but no joy yet. For reasons that I cant go into here, I need to use both "this" and another selector to bind a click event.. Example

```
    $('mySelector').each(function(){
    $(this, this.siblings('img')).bind('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        doStuffTo($(this));
    });
});
```

But I cant figure out how to do it. Anyone have any idea how I would achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the jQuery methods (that don't return a value) are automatically applied to each element in the collection, so `each()` is not necessary.

Combining `siblings()` and `andSelf()`, the code can be simplified to:

```
$('.mySelector').siblings('img').andSelf().click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    doStuffTo($(this));
});
```

Comment: I like yours better...it's cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Instead, you could do this:

```
$('mySelector').each(function(){
    $(this).siblings('img').andSelf()).bind('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        doStuffTo($(this));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, but perhaps it's this:

```
var f = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    doStuffTo($(this));
};

$('mySelector').each(function() {
   $(this).bind('click', f);
   $(this).siblings('img').bind('click', f);
});
```